# Debian 9 (Stretch), Python 3.8.17, "pip install numpy" is taking forever to install

Tags: pip, debian-stretch

**TL;DR:**

- I want to run Numpy and Pytorch on Debian 9
- I installed Python 3.8.17, installed virtualenv, created a virtual environment, and attempted to install Numpy on it
- However, the install takes forever and eventually gets stuck.

**Full Explanation:**

My ultimate goal is to set up a Python environment on Debian 9 so that I can run a PyTorch model on it, which from documentation seems to require Python 3.8 or above.

By default, Debian 9 comes with Python 3.5 which isn't sufficient. Thus, I installed Python 3.8.17 as outlined in this blog (https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-python-3-9-on-debian-9/) and confirmed that it works:

```
python3.8 -V     // Python 3.8.17
pip3.8 -V        //
```

Then, I used pip3.8 to install virtualenv and created a virtual environment to attempt to install Numpy using the command:

```
pip3.8 -v install numpy==1.24.4 --no-cache-dir
```

I've waited for 2 hours and it's been stuck with this message:

```
Using pip 23.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
  Link requires a different Python (3.8.17 not in: '>=3.9'): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/de/437a60a69f7fd0c79264530a97787b2ac7394616e366123620s-python:>=3.9)
  Link requires a different Python (3.8.17 not in: '>=3.9'): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/b2/fe774844d1857804cc884bba67bec38f649c99d0dc1ee7cbbfython:>=3.9)
Collecting numpy==1.24.4
  Downloading numpy-1.24.4.tar.gz (10.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.9/10.9 MB 2.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
  Collecting setuptools==59.2.0
    Using cached setuptools-59.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
  Collecting wheel==0.37.0
    Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting Cython<3.0,>=0.29.30
    Using cached Cython-0.29.35-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
  Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, Cython
  Successfully installed Cython-0.29.35 setuptools-59.2.0 wheel-0.37.0
  WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to us
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
  running egg_info
  running build_src
  INFO: build_src
  creating numpy.egg-info
  writing numpy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to numpy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to numpy.egg-info/entry_points.txt
  writing top-level names to numpy.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing manifest file 'numpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file 'numpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'LICENSES_bundled.txt'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-*.yml'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/source/generated'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'benchmarks/env'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'benchmarks/results'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'benchmarks/html'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'benchmarks/numpy'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.swp' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bak' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
  adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
  writing manifest file 'numpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Running from numpy source directory.
  
  ...

  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/build
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath
  INFO: compile options: '-Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Ibu/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/src/_simd -I/usr/locsrc.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
  INFO: gcc: numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c
  INFO: gcc: build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
  INFO: gcc: build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
  INFO: gcc: numpy/core/src/npymath/halffloat.c
  INFO: ar: adding 4 object files to build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/libnpymath.a
  INFO: building 'npyrandom' library
  INFO: compiling C sources
  INFO: C compiler: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC

  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/random
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/random/src
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/random/src/distributions
  INFO: compile options: '-Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/distutils/include -Inmpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/src/_simd -I/usr/local/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/nu
  extra options: '-std=c99'
  INFO: gcc: numpy/random/src/distributions/logfactorial.c
  INFO: gcc: numpy/random/src/distributions/distributions.c
  INFO: gcc: numpy/random/src/distributions/random_mvhg_count.c
  INFO: gcc: numpy/random/src/distributions/random_mvhg_marginals.c
  INFO: gcc: numpy/random/src/distributions/random_hypergeometric.c
  INFO: ar: adding 5 object files to build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/libnpyrandom.a
  running build_ext
  INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
  INFO: customize UnixCCompiler using new_build_ext
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.__init__[834] : hit the memory cache
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.generate_dispatch_header[2357] : generate CPU dispatch header: (build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/distutils/include/npy_cpu_dispatch_conf
  INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
  INFO: customize UnixCCompiler using new_build_ext
  INFO: building 'numpy.core._multiarray_tests' extension
  INFO: compiling C sources
  INFO: C compiler: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC

  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/common
  INFO: compile options: '-DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Inumpy/core/incl7l-3.8/numpy/distutils/include -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/um.8 -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
  INFO: gcc: build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c.src: In function ‘array_solve_diophantine’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c.src:1439:29: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
       if (PyTuple_GET_SIZE(U) != nterms) {
                               ^~
  INFO: gcc: numpy/core/src/common/mem_overlap.c
  INFO: gcc: numpy/core/src/common/npy_argparse.c
  INFO: gcc: numpy/core/src/common/npy_hashtable.c
  INFO: gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8common/npy_argparse.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/common/npy_hashtable.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8 -lnpymath -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8
  INFO: building 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' extension
  INFO: compiling C++ dispatch-able sources
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.parse_targets[1853] : looking for '@targets' inside ->  numpy/core/src/npysort/x86-qsort.dispatch.cpp
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2024] : skip targets (AVX512_SKX) not part of baseline or dispatch-able features
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2048] : policy 'KEEP_BASELINE' is ON
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2048] : policy 'MAXOPT' is ON
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._generate_config[2593] : generate dispatched config ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/x86-qsort.dispatch.h
  INFO: compiling C dispatch-able sources
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.parse_targets[1853] : looking for '@targets' inside ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2024] : skip targets (VX XOP VXE VSX2 AVX512_SKX AVX2 ASIMD SSE42 SSE2) not part of baseline or dispatch-able featu
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2048] : policy 'MAXOPT' is ON
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._generate_config[2593] : generate dispatched config ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.h
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._wrap_target[2553] : wrap dispatch-able target ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.neon.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.parse_targets[1853] : looking for '@targets' inside ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_unary_fp.dispatch.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2024] : skip targets (VX VXE VSX2 SSE41 ASIMD SSE2) not part of baseline or dispatch-able features
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2048] : policy 'MAXOPT' is ON
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._generate_config[2593] : generate dispatched config ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_unary_fp.dispatch.h
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._wrap_target[2553] : wrap dispatch-able target ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_unary_fp.dispatch.neon.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.parse_targets[1853] : looking for '@targets' inside ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_arithm_fp.dispatch.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2024] : skip targets (VXE VX AVX512F AVX2 SSE2) not part of baseline or dispatch-able features
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2048] : policy 'MAXOPT' is ON
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._generate_config[2593] : generate dispatched config ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_arithm_fp.dispatch.h
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.parse_targets[1853] : looking for '@targets' inside ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_arithmetic.dispatch.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2024] : skip targets (VX AVX512F VSX2 AVX512_SKX SSE41 VSX4 AVX2 SSE2) not part of baseline or dispatch-able featur
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2048] : policy 'MAXOPT' is ON
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._generate_config[2593] : generate dispatched config ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_arithmetic.dispatch.h
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._wrap_target[2553] : wrap dispatch-able target ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_arithmetic.dispatch.neon.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.parse_targets[1853] : looking for '@targets' inside ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_minmax.dispatch.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2024] : skip targets (VX VXE VSX2 AVX512_SKX AVX2 ASIMD SSE2) not part of baseline or dispatch-able features
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2048] : policy 'MAXOPT' is ON
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._generate_config[2593] : generate dispatched config ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_minmax.dispatch.h
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._wrap_target[2553] : wrap dispatch-able target ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_minmax.dispatch.neon.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.parse_targets[1853] : looking for '@targets' inside ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_trigonometric.dispatch.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2024] : skip targets (VXE2 (FMA3 AVX2) VXE VSX3 AVX512F VSX2 VSX4) not part of baseline or dispatch-able features
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2048] : policy 'MAXOPT' is ON
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._generate_config[2593] : generate dispatched config ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_trigonometric.dispatch.h
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._wrap_target[2553] : wrap dispatch-able target ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_trigonometric.dispatch.neon_vfp
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.parse_targets[1853] : looking for '@targets' inside ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_umath_fp.dispatch.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2024] : skip targets (AVX512_SKX) not part of baseline or dispatch-able features
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2048] : policy 'MAXOPT' is ON
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._generate_config[2593] : generate dispatched config ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_umath_fp.dispatch.h
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.parse_targets[1853] : looking for '@targets' inside ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_exponent_log.dispatch.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2024] : skip targets (AVX512_SKX (FMA3 AVX2) AVX512F) not part of baseline or dispatch-able features
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2048] : policy 'MAXOPT' is ON
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._generate_config[2593] : generate dispatched config ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_exponent_log.dispatch.h
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.parse_targets[1853] : looking for '@targets' inside ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_hyperbolic.dispatch.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2024] : skip targets ((FMA3 AVX2) VX VXE VSX2 AVX512_SKX VSX4) not part of baseline or dispatch-able features
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2048] : policy 'MAXOPT' is ON
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._generate_config[2593] : generate dispatched config ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_hyperbolic.dispatch.h
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._wrap_target[2553] : wrap dispatch-able target ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_hyperbolic.dispatch.neon_vfpv4.
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.parse_targets[1853] : looking for '@targets' inside ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_modulo.dispatch.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2024] : skip targets (VSX4) not part of baseline or dispatch-able features
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._generate_config[2593] : generate dispatched config ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_modulo.dispatch.h
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.parse_targets[1853] : looking for '@targets' inside ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_comparison.dispatch.c
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2024] : skip targets (VX VSX3 VXE AVX512F VSX2 AVX512_SKX AVX2 SSE42 SSE2) not part of baseline or dispatch-able fe
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2048] : policy 'MAXOPT' is ON
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._generate_config[2593] : generate dispatched config ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_comparison.dispatch.h
  INFO: CCompilerOpt._wrap_target[2553] : wrap dispatch-able target ->  build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_comparison.dispatch.neon.c
  INFO: C compiler: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC

  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath
  INFO: compile options: '-DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild/src.linuxc/common -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7t -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort .8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
  extra options: '-O3 -mfpu=neon'
  INFO: gcc: build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.neon.c
  In file included from build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.neon.c:8:0:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c.src: In function ‘simd_argmax_u32’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c.src:151:14: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
       if (len0 > NPY_MAX_UINT32) {
                ^
  In file included from build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.neon.c:8:0:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c.src: In function ‘simd_argmin_u32’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c.src:151:14: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
       if (len0 > NPY_MAX_UINT32) {
                ^
  In file included from build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.neon.c:8:0:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c.src: In function ‘simd_argmax_s32’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c.src:151:14: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
       if (len0 > NPY_MAX_UINT32) {
                ^
  In file included from build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.neon.c:8:0:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c.src: In function ‘simd_argmin_s32’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c.src:151:14: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
       if (len0 > NPY_MAX_UINT32) {
                ^
  In file included from build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.neon.c:8:0:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c.src: In function ‘simd_argmax_f32’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c.src:151:14: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
       if (len0 > NPY_MAX_UINT32) {
                ^
  In file included from build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.neon.c:8:0:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c.src: In function ‘simd_argmin_f32’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/argfunc.dispatch.c.src:151:14: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
       if (len0 > NPY_MAX_UINT32) {
                ^
  INFO: gcc: build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_unary_fp.dispatch.neon.c
  INFO: gcc: build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_arithmetic.dispatch.neon.c
  INFO: gcc: build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_minmax.dispatch.neon.c
  INFO: gcc: build/src.linux-armv7l-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_comparison.dispatch.neon.c
```

Since it can't even install Numpy properly (which is only ~35MB), PyTorch will for sure be an issue (which can be up to 1GB). What approach can I take to install these two packages properly on my machine? Or what am I doing wrong?

My hardware has limited memory and disk space, is it just inherently impossible to utilize PyTorch on this hardware?

Thanks in advance

---

Hardware Specifications:
Linux Command: lshw -short

```
TI AM335x BeagleBone Black 512MB DDR3 RAM, 4GB 8-bit eMMC on-board flash storage
```

Linux Command: lscpu

```
Architecture: armv71
CPU(s): 1
Model Name: ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v71)
```

Linux Command: cat /etc/*release

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
```

Comment: Numpy doesn't build wheels for Linux+ARM (and nor does PyTorch), so pip is trying to build numpy directly from its source. That may be a very intensive process. If you have access to a more powerful machine, you could try cross compiling. Numpy provides some [short cross compilation instructions here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/building.html#cross-compilation).

Comment: Cross compilation worked for Numpy and installing PyTorch, but PyTorch wasn't running properly so I am now experimenting with Tensorflow Lite. Thanks for the insight!